# ERROR: Failed building wheel for M2Crypto for django in WSL2

Tags: django, pip, wsl-2, python-poetry, m2crypto

I am trying to install some django dependencies however **m2crypto** seems to fail as in the following logs also there's an error below `unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory`. **I am also using WSL2**

```
  • Installing m2crypto (0.38.0): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///home/menna/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ef/3f/ce/4feb630731f44d2868dd6413e2dda6d6593c62852be40b8d43b7b6a029/M2Crypto-0.38.0.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output:
  Processing /home/menna/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ef/3f/ce/4feb630731f44d2868dd6413e2dda6d6593c62852be40b8d43b7b6a029/M2Crypto-0.38.0.tar.gz
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Building wheels for collected packages: M2Crypto
    Building wheel for M2Crypto (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for M2Crypto (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-u7uierq1
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/
    Complete output (61 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    copying src/M2Crypto/RC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/Engine.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/BN.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/Rand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/ASN1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/m2urllib2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/m2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/m2urllib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/m2crypto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/six.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/callback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/httpslib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/BIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/AuthCookie.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/m2xmlrpclib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/SMIME.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/X509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/EC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/ftpslib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/EVP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/Err.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    copying src/M2Crypto/DH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/ssl_dispatcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/SSLServer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Session.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Context.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Checker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/cb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Cipher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
    running egg_info
    writing src/M2Crypto.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/M2Crypto.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/M2Crypto.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/*.i'
    warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/*.h'
    warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/*.def'
    warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c'
    warning: no files found matching 'M2Crypto/m2crypto.py'
    adding license file 'LICENCE'
    writing manifest file 'src/M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'M2Crypto._m2crypto' extension
    swigging src/SWIG/_m2crypto.i to src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
    swig -python -py3 -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include -D__x86_64__ -I/home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/usr/include/openssl -includeall -modern -builtin -outdir /tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/src/M2Crypto -o src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c src/SWIG/_m2crypto.i
    unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for M2Crypto
    Running setup.py clean for M2Crypto
  Failed to build M2Crypto
  Installing collected packages: M2Crypto
      Running setup.py install for M2Crypto: started
      Running setup.py install for M2Crypto: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-s03g97z4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/include/site/python3.8/M2Crypto
           cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/
      Complete output (66 lines):
      running install
      /home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/RC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/Engine.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/BN.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/Rand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/ASN1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/m2urllib2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/m2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/m2urllib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/m2crypto.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/six.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/callback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/httpslib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/BIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/AuthCookie.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/m2xmlrpclib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/SMIME.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/X509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/EC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/ftpslib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/EVP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/Err.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      copying src/M2Crypto/DH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/ssl_dispatcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/SSLServer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Session.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Context.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Checker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/cb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      copying src/M2Crypto/SSL/Cipher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/M2Crypto/SSL
      running egg_info
      writing src/M2Crypto.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/M2Crypto.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/M2Crypto.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/*.i'
      warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/*.h'
      warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/*.def'
      warning: no files found matching 'SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c'
      warning: no files found matching 'M2Crypto/m2crypto.py'
      adding license file 'LICENCE'
      writing manifest file 'src/M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'M2Crypto._m2crypto' extension
      swigging src/SWIG/_m2crypto.i to src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
      swig -python -py3 -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include -D__x86_64__ -I/home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/usr/include/openssl -includeall -modern -builtin -outdir /tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/src/M2Crypto -o src/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c src/SWIG/_m2crypto.i
      unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
      error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ycua_cfq/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-s03g97z4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/include/site/python3.8/M2Crypto Check the logs for full command output.
  WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/home/menna/kr8/celo-digital-sports-card/api/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py:1183 in _run
      1179│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1180│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1181│                 )
      1182│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1183│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1184│
      1185│         return decode(output)
      1186│
      1187│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: "*`error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1`*" No, the error is "**unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory**"

Comment: yes edited it , do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Well, if there is no program named `swig` and the installation script requires it… let me guess… you need to install it, no? Install, add to `$PATH`, check from the command line if it's available, re-run the installation.

Comment: Dude, when the script says that you are missing `swig`, then you should install it. Read `INSTALL.rst`.